# Change flow of messages in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

Hello I'm new to Microsoft Bot Framework and I have a question that I couldn't find an answer to.
I have a FormFlow that ask the user for some question, after a specific question I want the bot to do some logic and show messages accordingly (for example if the user selected option 1 then show message X and if the user selected option 2 show message Y).

Here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Bot_CRM.FormFlow
{
    public enum RequestOptions { Unknown, CheckStatus, CreateCase };

    [Serializable]
    public class CaseFormFlow
    {
        public RequestOptions RequestType;
        [Prompt("What is your first name?")]
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
        public string ContactNumber;
        [Prompt("Please enter your id")]
        public string Id;

        public static IForm<CaseFormFlow> BuildForm()
        {
            OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<CaseFormFlow> processRequest = async (context, state) =>
            {
                await context.PostAsync($@"Thanks for your request");
            };

            return new FormBuilder<CaseFormFlow>()
                   .Message("Hello and welcom to my service desk bot")
                   .Field(nameof(FirstName))
                   .Message("hello {FirstName}")
                   .Field(nameof(Id))
                   .Field(nameof(RequestType)) => 
//here if user select 1 start flow of check status and if user select 2 start flow of create case
                   .AddRemainingFields()
                   .Message("Thank you request. Our help desk team will get back to you shortly.")
                   .OnCompletion(processRequest)
                   .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Updated code after Ezequiel's suggestion:

```
 return new FormBuilder<CaseFormFlow>()
               .Message("Hello and welcom to my service desk bot")
               .Field(nameof(FirstName))
               .Message("hello {FirstName}")
               .Field(new FieldReflector<CaseFormFlow>(nameof(RequestType))
                .SetActive(state => state.AskUserForRequestType)
                .SetNext((value, state) =>
                {
                    var selection = (RequestOptions)value;

                    if (selection == RequestOptions.CheckStatus)
                    {

                        return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(Id) });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new NextStep();
                    }
                }))
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great question.The key thing is to use the SetActive and SetNext methods of the [`Field<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.formflow.advanced.field-1?view=botbuilder-3.12.2.4) class. You should consider using the [FieldReflector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.formflow.advanced.fieldreflector-1?view=botbuilder-3.12.2.4) class; though you can implement your own IField.

SetActive is described in the [Dynamic Fields section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-formbuilder?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#dynamically-define-field-values-confirmations-and-messages) of the FormFlow documentation. Basically it provides a delegate that enables the field based on a condition.

SetNext will allow you to decide what step of the form should come next based on your custom logic.

You can take a look to the [ContosoFlowers](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/) sample. In the [Order](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/Models/Order.cs#L93) form; something similar is being done.

```
 public static IForm<Order> BuildOrderForm()
        {
            return new FormBuilder<Order>()
                .Field(nameof(RecipientFirstName))
                .Field(nameof(RecipientLastName))
                .Field(nameof(RecipientPhoneNumber))
                .Field(nameof(Note))
                .Field(new FieldReflector<Order>(nameof(UseSavedSenderInfo))
                    .SetActive(state => state.AskToUseSavedSenderInfo)
                    .SetNext((value, state) =>
                    {
                        var selection = (UseSaveInfoResponse)value;

                        if (selection == UseSaveInfoResponse.Edit)
                        {
                            state.SenderEmail = null;
                            state.SenderPhoneNumber = null;
                            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(SenderEmail) });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return new NextStep();
                        }
                    }))
                .Field(new FieldReflector<Order>(nameof(SenderEmail))
                    .SetActive(state => !state.UseSavedSenderInfo.HasValue || state.UseSavedSenderInfo.Value == UseSaveInfoResponse.Edit)
                    .SetNext(
                        (value, state) => (state.UseSavedSenderInfo == UseSaveInfoResponse.Edit)
                        ? new NextStep(new[] { nameof(SenderPhoneNumber) })
                        : new NextStep()))
                .Field(nameof(SenderPhoneNumber), state => !state.UseSavedSenderInfo.HasValue || state.UseSavedSenderInfo.Value == UseSaveInfoResponse.Edit)
                .Field(nameof(SaveSenderInfo), state => !state.UseSavedSenderInfo.HasValue || state.UseSavedSenderInfo.Value == UseSaveInfoResponse.Edit)
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help,
when trying to implement the code I received the following error:
'Field<CaseFormFlow>' does not contain a definition for 'SetNext' and no extension method 'SetNext' accepting a first argument of type 'Field<CaseFormFlow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

can you point my in the direction of the dll that I'm missing?

Thanks again

Comment: The methods are from the FieldReflector class. Take a look to the code snippet, you will have to define your field as Field(new FieldReflector<CaseFormFlow)(nameof(YourFieldName)

Comment: this is what i did when i got the error

I added the code in the question
Thanks again for the help

Comment: Make sure you have the expected usings: using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.Advanced;

Comment: I got it to work, Thanks for all the help
At the end the problem was in the template dll that were not at the lates version.
after I re-complied the sdk solution and copied the dll it's work

Again Thank you very much for all of your help

Comment: Glad it worked. You should consider using the nuget package instead of manually building the assemblies.